# iOS update rejection - location permission modal alert

Tags: ios, validation, permissions, location

I have an iOS app on the app store that can:

- show the user location on a map when the user clicks on a GPS button
- record a tracking of the user location when the user clicks on a record button

That app passed validation in the past. I recently made an update that changes nothing to the location stuff, and that has been refused because of the message displayed when requesting the location permission to show the user location on a map (so, when the user clicks on the GPS button).

The message was:

> MyAppName needs to access your location to show it on the map.

Seemed pretty clear to me, but reading the guidelines I saw that we should not display the app name. So I updated it to:

> Your current location will be displayed on the map.

Which is nearly the same as the message of [the guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission). Rejected again.  When the user clicks on the GPS button, the app does nothing more than showing the location on the map.

When the user clicks on the record button, a different message is displayed:

> Your current location will be used to record a tracking. The setting must be set to "Always Allow" in order to record the tracking even when the app is in the background.

I explained all of that in an answer to the app rejection message and I'm waiting Apple's response. In the mean time, in order to avoid losing even more time, I'd like to know if someone ran into a similar problem, and what message did you display to pass validation?

Comment: I tried with `This app needs to use your current location for tracking.` and my app was not rejected after it.

Comment: Thanks, but when the user clicks on the GPS button (to show his location on the map, not to start a tracking), I don't want to ask for the unneeded "Always" permission, hence the 2 different messages. Does your app also allow showing the location and starting a tracking independently?

Comment: no..my app had different purpose actually. :) but `This app needs to use your current location for` this much portion was common

Comment: Agreed, I don't understand the rejection :/ . As I've said I answered, but I've been waiting their response for 3 days now. Not sure if I need to appeal the rejection or just wait more.

Answer (score 2):

Sooooo in the end, they validated my app, after a new message explaining in details the two different use cases (leading to the two different permission requests message).